# Low state simulation on keil micro vision

Tags: c, microcontroller, keil

Sorry to ask for something so simple, and for the possible faults that you will see in the code, i am starting in this programming software. As a student I have a project to do:

I have to simulate a button on board a robot which simulates an ephemeral low level support for 10ms in C on keil micro vision.

I tried with this code to fill the task but it does not work at all ...

Thank you in advance, if you need additional information to understand my problem do not hesitate, thank you

(EINT0 and T0 are for the 10ms low state)

```
#include "LPC23xx.h"


void isr_EINT0()__irq{

      if (FIO2PIN!=1){
              if (T0MR0==12000*10){
                    T0TCR=2;
                    FIO2PIN=FIO2PIN^1;
             }

      }

    if(FIO2PIN==1){

         T0TCR=1;
         FIO2PIN=FIO2PIN^1;
     }



  EXTINT=0x01;
  VICVectAddr=0;

} 

void init_EINT0(void){
     //on desire que la fonction périphérique EINT1  soit activée : 
     PINSEL4 =1<<20;
     FIO2DIR=0x01;
     FIO2CLR=0x01;  
// configurer l'interruption externe 1 sur le bon front
       EXTMODE = 1;// les interruptions sont actives sur front (en fait seuls deux sont utiles
       EXTPOLAR = 0;// int0 front montant, int1 sur front descendant,
    // configuration des vecteurs d it
    //acquittement du flag d it0,it1, pour ne pas générer d IT intempestives;

    //autorisation des interruptions

    VICVectAddr14=(unsigned long)isr_EINT0;
    VICIntEnable=(1<<14);

 }
void isr_EINT1()__irq{

    FIO2PIN=FIO2PIN^1;

EXTINT=0x02;
VICVectAddr=0;


}
void init_EINT1(void){
     //on desire que la fonction périphérique EINT1  soit activée : 
     PINSEL4 =1<<22;    
     FIO2DIR=0x01;
     FIO2CLR=0x01;
// configurer l'interruption externe 1 sur le bon front
       EXTMODE =2;// les interruptions sont actives sur front (en fait seuls deux sont utiles
       EXTPOLAR=0;// int0 front montant, int1 sur front descendant,
    // configuration des vecteurs d it
    //acquittement du flag d it0,it1, pour ne pas générer d IT intempestives;

    //autorisation des interruptions

    VICVectAddr15=(unsigned long)isr_EINT1;
    VICIntEnable=(1<<15);

 }

void init_gpo(void){
PINSEL4=0;
FIO2DIR=1;
FIO2PIN=0x01;
    }

void init_processeur(void)
{ // on interdit toutes les sources d interruptions
  // c est normalement inutile mais ca fait relire la doc...
         VICIntEnClr = 0xFF;
}


void isr_T0()__irq{

      if (FIO2PIN!=1){
              if (T0MR0==12000*10){
                    T0TCR=2;
                    FIO2PIN=FIO2PIN^1;
               }

      }


  T0IR=1;
  VICVectAddr=0;

} 
void init_T0(void){
// prescalaire

         FIO2DIR=0x01;
        // T0TCR=0x03; //Timer0 en mode Timer  et reset du timer
// timer match register
       T0MR0 =12000*10; // au dela de 1seconde on a une erreur, on doit lancer une IT disant que le bit est mauvais ou que le ROBOT a disparu
       T0MCR = 0x03; // l evenement de match sur l arrivee a une seconde indique une absence de ROBOT

        // T0IR =0x01 ; //acquittement d'un it parasite precedente

 // configurer pour avoir une capture externe sur une patte  (trouver comment configurer un pinsel pour avoir une patte configurée en mat0.0
         //PINSEL4= 1<<20; //modifier x
 // configurer les registres pour avoir une capture sur front descendant
       // T0CCR=0x06 ;       

 //configuration de l'interruption


         //T0TCR = 0x01;//miser en route du timer

    VICVectAddr4=(unsigned long)isr_T0;
    VICIntEnable=(1<<4);
}


void init_proc(void)
 {  //port2.0 a port2.15 en entree sortie normale
   init_gpo(); 
   init_T0();
   init_EINT0();
     //init_EINT1();
     //init_EINT2();
     // init_EINT3();
 }


int main(void)
{            
    init_proc();     
     //init_var_global();
    while(1)           
    {//temoin de vie  
     // Test de flag de reception de trame complete ...   
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow; please update your post to include the text in the post itself - it's frowned upon to use offsite links for code (especially images)

Comment: Hello Steve,

I'm just getting started on this website and I'm starting to understand the different parameters to ask a question properly.

Thank you very much ! @SteveFriedl

Comment: Hi Sarah: thank you for this, I hope somebody who understands this microprocessor is able to help you

Comment: Hi, your question is not clear enough. Are you trying to run this code on a keil emulator and it's failing?  *ephemeral low level support for 10ms*, what do you mean by that? EINT0 is the button interrupt?

Comment: Hello,

Sorry for the lack of clarity I have been studying microcontrollers for only a few months and I do not speak fluent English ...

Here is my exact statement:
  "a simulator of the buttons on board the robot (emergency stop, recovery, parcel taken available) and the robot number is required

     Pressing the emergency stop changes the state of the button from ON to OFF and vice versa, the other buttons simulate an ephemeral low level press for 10 ms., The simulation stops spontaneously 15 ms after the start. "

Thank you for your attention to my question!

Comment: EINT1 is for the emergency ON to OFF and EINT0 for the ephemeral low level.   
When I launch my code it compiles well without any warning but during the simulation, when I press the button it does not do what I want ...

Comment: --------- @xvan

Comment: Please look into the usage of [`clang-format`](https://leimao.github.io/blog/Clang-Format-Quick-Tutorial/), your code formatting is unreadable to us and unhelpful to you.